# override translation fallback symfony 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have a symfony 2 project that supports 2 languages in both the backend and the front end. And I have enabled translation fallback in the configuration to allow the admin to view all the database records regardless of what language he chooses to use in the backend. However, for the front end of the website I wish to disable the fallback. How can I override the translation fallback from true to false in only the controllers I want?

I am using Gedmo translatable in my entities to translate specific columns.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found it http://blog.lazycloud.net/symfony2-doctrine2-extentions-translatable/

Apparently I should add to my entity a $locale attribute and set above it the annotation  * @Gedmo\Locale . and then I can use that to override the default fallback of the entity by seting the locale to whatever language I wish then calling $em->refresh($entity)

Answer (score 1):

The locale of the current user is stored in the request and is accessible via the request object like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $locale = $request->getLocale();

    $request->setLocale('en_US');
}
```

More details [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#handling-the-user-s-locale)

I think this is what you are looking for.
Using this you can override locale settings.

If you want to set fallback locale you can do that also, using:

```
$translator->setFallbackLocale(array('en'));
```

More Details given [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation/introduction.html#fallback-locales)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Nope, I know about this, that is not it. Even if I change the locale, if an entity does not have a translation for this locale it is showing me the other locale. I need a way to prevent this fallback on a given controller while allowing it on others.

Comment: then @JoeYahchouchi you should see this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html#translations

"The file that always wins is the one that is placed in app/Resources/translations, as those files are always loaded last."

Comment: This is for static entities, I am referring to dynamic entities translated with Gedmo...

Comment: updated my answer have you tried setFallbackLocale()?

Comment: Didn't work, but nice try. I think the translator is for the static words that have |trans, and not for the entities doctrine loads directly from the database. This fallback in the config is under stof_doctrine_extensions: translation_fallback I need a way to retrieve and modify that from the controller

Comment: I really need to mention here that you have not mentioned any of such things in you question that you need to translate data coming from DB. Please update your question.